# Как корректно аутентифицироваться?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

После попытки скомпилировать код, появилось исключение (exception - 28P01) - см. скриншот.
Используется драйвер Npgsql. В силу не читаемых символов трудно разобраться в чём дело.

Заранее благодарю за совет!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот на этом сайте: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/static/errcodes-appendix.html пишут, что сия ошибка означает, что Вы указали неверный пароль. Проверьте корректность строки подключения.

Comment: Оказалось, порт был не тот. Спасибо!